# How should I ask questions containing a qt project?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have currently the problem that I have a problem with a [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) project. When I want to provide a minimal running sample of my project, it needs already just for being able to compile four different files (qt-project file, main file and subclass files). This would lead to a quite large question, containing necessary information for compiling, but most of the code is not contributing to the question itself. How should I handle that?

Comment: Can you isolate the the problem to a "widget" or two or similar that doesn't work? Eg, if you question would were: "When I click this button - it doesn't fill this textbox" - what's wrong? Then post the appropriate code there.

Comment: What is `r`, or what do you mean with that?

Comment: Just hit enter too soon :)

Comment: @JonClements: The problem is already reduced to a command line function, and is more about functions in qt and networking, so I tried to reduce it already

Comment: Since you seem to be willing spending time to make sure your question is on-topic and answerable, one option is to create a gist of your reduced code, along with what your question is, and the community reading this post can potentially offer advice whether it's suitable or not, and if not how to make it so.